# How To Search a User in Discourse Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find and delete unwanted user in my discourse using ruby

```
puts "Search Member you want to Delete"

puts "Search By E-Mail"

usermail = gets

puts client.search(usermail)
```

in result it takes me to discourse page 
is there any possible ways to search and find the exact user by email. 
thanks for your nice and helpful comments

Comment: What's `search`?

Comment: Don't forget input from `gets` often has a newline on the end. You want `usermail = gets.chomp`.

Comment: @tadman I used chomp too but its not giving me

Comment: Giving you...? What?

Comment: when i run the script its not getting executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get a user by name using Http gem 
require 'http'
username = 'username'
response = HTTP.get("https://discourse.example.com/user/#{username}.jason?api_key=Your_Discourse_api_key")
puts response.body.to_s

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

i think we cannot search users by email and we can just use the following for geting users list
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {params: {id: 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}}